# Ansible Copy Command not working with remote machine wild char

Tags: ansible, copy, devops

Copy command doesn't work with wild card character.

Playbook:

```
- name: Copy Delta Updated Files To All ABC 
  copy:
    src: /opt/SP/users/runner/DEV/ABC/DRF221/DELTA_UPDATE/
    dest: ~/JEE/ABC/config_files/ABC-FULL/ABC*_1_DRF221
    mode: preserve
  tags:
    - storage
```

Error:

```
fatal: [DEV_ABC]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/opt/SP/users/dev/JEE/ABC/config_files/ABC-FULL/ABC_*_1_DRF221/Text.xml): Not a directory"}**
```

Comment: you may want to take a look into fileglob : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use wild card in copy command. You need to first find the directory and then copy.

```
  - name: find files
    find:
     paths: /opt/SP/users/dev/JEE/ABC/config_files/ABC-FULL/
     file_type: directory
     patterns: "ABC_*_1_DRF221"
    register: output

  - name: copy
    copy:
     src: /opt/SP/users/runner/DEV/ABC/DRF221/DELTA_UPDATE/
     dest: "{{item.path}}"
    with_items: "{{output.files}}"
```

If the src file is remote, use remote_src:true